# Игнорирование child'ов при наведении на panel WinForms

Tags: c#, winforms

Вот у нас есть panel, и на ней всякие другие элементы, например label. И в panel, есть событие MouseHover (оно срабатывает, когда мышь наведена на объект), в которой есть функция, которая меняет цвет фона. Но если я наведу на label внутри той panel, то функция в MouseHover перестанет работать. Как сделать так, что бы при наведении на child'ы панели, работала функция в MouseHover именно в panel, а не на этом чилде

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Можно все child'ы подписать на то же самое событие:

```
foreach (Control control in panel.Controls)
{
    control.MouseHover += Panel_MouseHover;
    //control.MouseLeave += Panel_MouseLeave;
}
```